# @Autowired by constructor looks for beans by type. How to inject a bean by name to a constructor using autowired annotation

Tags: spring-annotations, spring-3

`@Autowired` by constructor looks for beans by type. How to inject a bean by name to a constructor using autowired  annotation?
I have 2 beans of same type but I need to inject it to constructor of another same class based on the bean name. How do I do it?

XML:

```
 <bean id="A" class="com.Check"/>
 <bean id="B" class="com.Check"/>
```

Java:

```
Class C {

   private Check check;

   @Autowired
   public C(Check check){
       this.check = check
   }

  }
```

When I do this I get an exception telling me that I have 2 beans of same type check but it requires there to be just one bean of that type. How can I inject the bean with `id="B"` into this class `C` through constructor injection?

In my `applicationContext.xml` I have mentioned `autowire="byType"`. I need to autowire `byName` only in this particular class rest all it needs to be autowired by Type only

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use @Qualifier annotation with your target bean id for constructor parameter.

```
<bean id="A" class="com.Check"/>
<bean id="B" class="com.Check"/>

Class C {

   private Check check;

   @Autowired
   public C(@Qualifier("A") Check check){ //<-- here you should provide your target bean id
      this.check = check
   }
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. 

I used 
          @Autowired
 public CheckDAO(@Qualifier("entityManager")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
  
  em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  
 }

im getting this exception.
       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'checkDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 2